# Get the exact child Table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation here...
I have two div's content1 and content2,each div has a table also...
so i get each table like this

```
$("#content1 table") 
or 
$("#content2 table")
```

but I want Like this

```
var x="#content1" or "#content2"
```

then something like this

```
$(x "table")
```

i.e pass the id to a variable and get the table... any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in the example you gave itself. Just have to modify it slightly

```
var x="#content1"; //whatever the name of the parent is
$resulting_table = $(x+" table")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Its great.But why the space is given there?

Comment: @Krishna That describes that we are going to look for a descendant element.

Answer (score 4):

```
    var x= document.getElementById('content1');
     $(x).find("table");
```

try this one

Answer (score 2):

You can combine selector using comma by [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$("#content1 table, #content2 table")
```

Alternatively you can assign common class to table with #content1 and #content2

```
$('.common-table-class')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the `context` i.e] [`$('selector',context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1),

```
var x= "#content1";
var table = $('table', x);
```

And the above code is very much similar to,

```
var x= "#content1";
var table = $(x).find("table");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  **[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**  to get the table

```
 $(x).find("table");
```

Answer (score 2):

use find function `$(x).find("table")`

Answer (score 1):

For more simplicity:

```
$(x + " table");
```